# Unexpected high resources consumption from gnome-javascript

Tags: freeze, crash, ubuntu-gnome, javascript

I'm running Ubuntu Lunar 23.04. I've acceptable computing resources but for some reason the GNOME desktop environment keeps freezing for a moment then it returns back to normal without crashing, however this issue is consistent. I checked what's using up all my resources and I got the following.

[image: here]

Process 19555 was gjs and it consumed 72% of memory and 100% of the CPU. After I killed the process the computer got back to functioning probably as you can see on the graphs, but I have to kill this process every time my computer slows up. Does anyone have any idea why is this is happening?

Comment: Can you try by disabling all GNOME addons (extensions) and then enabling them one-by-one? To access the **Extensions** config tool, first press the Windows key and then type **Extensions**.

Comment: @FedKad Works for me! thanks.

Comment: Which was the problematic extension? You can simply answer your own Question and give more info, instead of saying that it just _works_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the brave browser which created a bad extension in gjs, I removed the browser which i installed with snap and reinstalled it using apt.